# Using Scrapy to crawl websites and only scrape pages containing keywords

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl various websites looking for particular keywords of interest and only scraping those pages. I've written the script to run as a standalone Python script rather than the traditional `Scrapy` project structure (following this [example](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610)) and using the `CrawlSpider` class. The idea is that from a given homepage the `Spider` will crawl pages within that domain and only scrape links from pages which contain the keyword. I'm also trying to save a copy of the page when I find one containing the keyword.  The previous version of this question related to a syntax error (see comments below, thanks @tegancp for helping me clear that up) but now although my code runs I am still unable to crawl links only on pages of interest as intended.

I think I want to either i) remove the call to `LinkExtractor` in the `__init__` function or ii) only call `LinkExtractor` from within `__init__` but with a rule based on what I find when I visit that page rather than some attribute of the URL. I can't do i) because the `CrawlSpider` class wants a rule and I can't do ii) because `LinkExtractor` doesn't have a `process_links` option like the old `SgmlLinkExtractor` which appears to be deprecated.  I'm new to Scrapy so wondering if my only option is to write my own `LinkExtractor`?

```
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose, TakeFirst
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy import log, signals, Spider, Item, Field
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from twisted.internet import reactor


# define an item class
class GenItem(Item):
    url = Field()

# define a spider
class GenSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "genspider3"

    # requires 'start_url', 'allowed_domains' and 'folderpath' to be passed as string arguments IN THIS PARTICULAR ORDER!!!
    def __init__(self):

        self.start_urls = [sys.argv[1]]
        self.allowed_domains = [sys.argv[2]]
        self.folder = sys.argv[3]
        self.writefile1 = self.folder + 'hotlinks.txt'
        self.writefile2 = self.folder + 'pages.txt'

        self.rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(sys.argv[2],)), follow=True, callback='parse_links')]
        super(GenSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        # get list of links on start_url page and process using parse_links
        list(self.parse_links(response))

    def parse_links(self, response):
       # if this page contains a word of interest save the HTML to file and crawl the links on this page

        theHTML = response.body
        if 'keyword' in theHTML:
            with open(self.writefile2, 'a+') as f2:
                f2.write(theHTML + '\n')
            with open(self.writefile1, 'a+') as f1:
                f1.write(response.url + '\n')


            for link in LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(sys.argv[2],)).extract_links(response):
                linkitem = GenItem()
                linkitem['url'] = link.url
                log.msg(link.url)
                with open(self.writefile1, 'a+') as f1:
                    f1.write(link.url + '\n')
                return linkitem



# callback fired when the spider is closed
def callback(spider, reason):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()  # collect/log stats?

    # stop the reactor
    reactor.stop()


# instantiate settings and provide a custom configuration
settings = Settings()
#settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT', 2)
settings.set('DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 0.25)

# instantiate a crawler passing in settings
crawler = Crawler(settings)

# instantiate a spider
spider = GenSpider()

# configure signals
crawler.signals.connect(callback, signal=signals.spider_closed)

# configure and start the crawler
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()

# start logging
log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)

# start the reactor (blocks execution)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Looks like the syntax error is not actually on that line, but on the previous line, which is missing a close parenthesis.  Also you may want to consider just using a single LinkExtractor.

Comment: thanks @tegancp that was the issue, although there were plenty more, one of which I may need to raise another question about but with that syntax problem sorted at least I made some progress!

Comment: Decide to just edit original question since the title still applies, I'm new to StackOverflow so apologies if this isn't usually how things are done

Comment: Does it work if you use `return self.parse_links(response)` in `parse_start_url()` instead?